# NextJS behind proxy with URL Rewrite

Tags: nginx, next.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

**Context:**

I've a NextJS deployment behind Nginx. The idea is to use NextJS to create several websites hosted in different domains. Each domain will have an entry in Nginx and it will be pointing to the specific path `pages/cafes/[cafeId]` in NextJS. There will be only one NextJs deployment for all websites and each domain will be routed using `static` proxy in nginx.

*nginx.conf*

```
   server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.cafe-one.local;
        location = / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/cafes/cafe_id_1;
            ...
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            ...
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.cafe-two.local;
        location = / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/cafes/cafe_id_2;
            ...
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            ...
        }
    }
```

*pages/[cafeId]/index.js*

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  return {
    paths: [], // no website rendered during build time, there are around 1000+ sites
    fallback: true
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async context => {

  const cafeId = context.params.cafeId;
  const cafe = await ... // get data from server

  return {
    props: {
      cafe
    },
    revalidate: 10 // revalidate every 10 seconds
  };
};

export default function CafeWebsite(props) {
  const router = useRouter();

  // getStaticProps() is not finished
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  
  return <div>{props.cafe.name}</div>;
}
```

**Issue:**

When I access `www.cafe-one.local`, i get to the loading screen, but then NextJS throw **a client-side error** about the `The provided as value (/) is incompatible with the href value (/cafes/[cafeId])`. This is understandable because the current URL is not what NextJS is expecting.

[image]

**Question:**

How to fix the issue, such that NextJS could be used in front of Nginx reverse proxy?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, have you found any solution?

Comment: Also running into the same problem.. very curious if you ever found a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Edit Oct 2021: Next.js 12 now supports [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware), which can achieve dynamic subdomains without the need for a proxy server. See [an official example](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-functions/hostname-rewrites).

---

Original answer: Thanks to Ale for the replaceState idea, this is how we handle it now:

1. Nginx proxies all initial requests to our vercel deployment with `/original.host.com/` as the first item in the path:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    # redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    # (not needed if you set assetPrefix in next.config.js to https://myapp.com)
    location /_next {
        proxy_pass https://myapp.com;
    }

    # a separate line for root is needed to bypass nginx messing up the request uri
    location = / {
        proxy_pass https://myapp.com/$host;
    }

    # this is the primary proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://myapp.com/$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

2. In `_app.tsx`, we register an effect that runs after Next.js finishes changing the route (this isn't triggered on the first render).

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const handleRouteChange = (url: string) => {
    const paths = url.split('/')

    if (paths[1] === location.host) {
      // remove /original.host.com/ from the path
      // note that passing history.state as the first argument makes back/forward buttons work correctly
      history.replaceState(history.state, '', `/${paths.slice(2).join('/')}`)
    }
  }

  router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)

  return () => {
    router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
  }
}, [])
```

3. All domain-specific pages are under `pages/[domain]/`, e.g. `pages/[domain]/mypage.tsx`.
4. Finally, we prepend the original hostname to each `href`, like

   - `<Link href="/original.host.com/mypage">...</Link>` or
   - `Router.push('/original.host.com/mypage')`.

   There's no need to use `as` anymore.
5. Next.js will now navigate to `https://original.host.com/original.host.com/mypage` for a split second, and then replace it with `https://original.host.com/mypage` once the transition is complete.
6. To make SSR work for each domain-specific page, we add `getStaticPaths`/`getStaticProps` in each of our pages so that Next.js knows to generate a separate version of the page for each domain (otherwise `router.query.domain` will be empty while in SSR and we'd get errors that the paths mismatch). Note that this doesn't negatively affect performance because the page will be cached after the first request.

```js
// In pages/[domain]/mypage.tsx

export default function MyPage(params: MyPageProps) {
  const router = useRouter()
  // SSR provides domain as a param, client takes it from router.query
  const domain = params.domain || router.query.domain

  // ... rest of your page
}

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => ({
  fallback: 'blocking',
  paths: [],
})

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<SpaceEditPageProps> = async ({
  params,
}) => {
  return {
    props: {
      domain: params?.domain as string,
    },
  }
}
```

7. Bonus tip: To see the final URL when the user hovers a Link, we don't use `passHref` but instead set the fake URL as `href`, cancel default action in `onClickCapture`, and trigger the router in `onClick` (you can extract this into a reusable component):

```js
<Link href="/original.host.com/mypage">
  <a
    href="/mypage"
    onClick={() => Router.push("/original.host.com/mypage")}
    onClickCapture={e => e.preventDefault()}
  >
    // ...
  </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Wow.. thank you so much - have spent almost the whole day to figure out that nginx needs that second / to prevent messing up the URL. I still don't really get why though. Could you shine some light on this? Thank you so much - saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with the same issue, but for mapping different subdomains to a dynamic route in the NextJS app.

I haven't been able to find a proper solution to the `The provided as value (/) is incompatible with the href value` error, but I found a somewhat hacky workaround.

First, you have to redirect the requests from `my-domain.com` to `my-domain.com/path-to-dynamic-route`. Then you have to reverse proxy all request from `my-domain.com/path-to-dynamic-route` to the same dynamic route in the NextJS app, like `localhost:3000/path-to-dynamic-route`.

You can do it manually from NGINX with a combination of `return 301` and `proxy_pass`, or you can let NextJS do it automatically by passing the dynamic route in the `proxy_pass` directive with a trailing slash.

`nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.cafe-one.local;
    location = / {
        # When a url to a route has a trailing slash, NextJS responds with a "308 Permanent redirect" to the path without the slash.
        # In this case from /cafes/cafe_id_1/ to /cafes/cafe_id_1
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/cafes/cafe_id_1/;
        # If you also want to be able to pass parameters in the query string, you should use the variable $request_uri instead of "/"
        # proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/cafes/cafe_id_1$request_uri;
        ...
    }
    location / {
        # Any other request to www.cafe-one.local will keep the original route and query string
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000$request_uri;
        ...
    }
}
```

This should work, but now we have a problem with the url in the address bar. Any user visiting `www.cafe-one.local` will be redirected to `www.cafe-one.local/cafes/cafe_id_1` and that doesn't look nice.

The only workaround I found to solve this issue was to use javascript to remove the path by rewriting the browsing history with `window.history.replaceState()`.

`pages/[cafeId]/index.js`

```
...
export default function CafeWebsite(props) {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    window.history.replaceState(null, "", "/")
  }
...
```

if you don't want to remove the path for all domains, you can use `window.location.hostname` to check the current url.

```
...
export default function CafeWebsite(props) {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const hostname = window.location.hostname
    const regex = /^(www\.my-domain\.|my-domain\.)/
    if (!regex.test(hostname)) {
      window.history.replaceState(null, "", "/")
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: Thanks Ale for your reply. Something I've understood working with NextJS is that the URL on the client-side and server-side is tightly integrated, because of the SSR nature of the nextJS app, any attempts to disconnect these 2 leads you down the rabbit-hole.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to handle the same issue by forcing my dynamic pages to use ONLY serverside rendering.

The fact is, Next tries to hydrate route params from the browser page URL which is outside of Next's context due to nginx.